# Find sync with foreach in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want create a sync query inside for with mongoose.

My script is:

```
async.parallel(
    {
        team: function(callback){
            Object.keys(myobj[0]).each(function(name){
                db.model( 'myCollection', myCollection, myCollection ).find({ profile: name }, function( err, profile ){
                    if (err)
                        return callback(err);
                    callback(null, profile);
                });
            });
        },
    },
    function(e, r){
        console.log(r.team);
        // can use r.team
    }
);
```

but i have this error

Error: Callback was already called.

Comment: Your code calls the callback for `each` result ... you can only call the `callback` once. It's not clear what you're trying to do though actually?

Answer (score 0):

```
team: function(callback){
            Object.keys(myobj[0]).each(function(name){
                db.model( 'myCollection', myCollection, myCollection ).find({ profile: name }, function( err, profile ){
                    if (err)
                        return callback(err);
                    callback(null, profile);
                });
            });
        },
```

It's not going to work , since the callback will be executed as soon as the first result is found in your forEach (`each` is not valid javascript BTW). Check async docs for async.map or modify the mongoose query to find all the documents that match an an array of profiles, so you execute only 1 query and get back an array of profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of functions and use clojure to keep hold of each array element.

```
function createfunc(obj) {
    var name = obj;

    return function(callback) {
        db.model( 'myCollection', myCollection, myCollection ).find({ profile: name }, function( err, profile ){
                    if (err)
                        return callback(err);
                    callback(null, profile);
                });
    }
}

var funcs = [];
Object.keys(myobj[0]).forEach(function(name) { funcs.push(createfunc(name)); });

async.parallel(funcs, function(e, r) { console.log(r.team); });
```